# The outer layer of my skin is showing up on the inside of my skin

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing Minecraft for about a month now, and I've made a couple skins, and both of them have an outer layer. They don't show up on my screen, so I thought it showed up for everyone else and that it was just a glitch.

While I was doing a modded survival, I accidentally went into the front view mode while mining a tree. Then I saw the outside layer on the INSIDE of my skin. I was hoping I could get some help on why this is happening. I've added screenshots of my outside layer on the inside and my two skins to see if anyone recognizes what's wrong.

[image]

- [image]
- [image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVA5f.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnDfK.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUpgk.png

Comment: Does the same happen in Vanilla? And if not, what mods are you using?

Comment: Yes in Vanilla it still doesnt show up. I'm unsure if its on the inside or not. The mods im using are just the travellers backpack and baubles

Comment: Does it show inside your head in Vanilla?

Comment: Yes i just checked it still shows up on the inside in the latest release.

Comment: Right now im testing flipping around my head and hood in paint.net so i'll update this when i've tested

Comment: Update: It worked. I'm just doing finishing touches and i'll be done. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: So you actually had the two switched? Then you can post that as an answer.

Comment: Boy, I wish this were on Hot Network Questions.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is switch the head and outer layer around in a program like paint.net that supports transparency.